# Use sed to change conf file

Tags: linux, sed

I'm trying to set some numeric values in my nginx.conf file.
I'm calling sed from the RUN command in my Dockerfile.

Specifically I'm wanting to change what is currently:

```
worker_processes 4;
```

To:

```
worker_processes 1;
```

Regular expressions are powerful, but $*(&(*Y hard to make work.

I found this, which works.

```
 sed -i '/access_log/s|/[^;]\+|/dev/stdout|' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

But modified to this and it doesn't.

```
 sed -i '/worker_processes/s|/[^;]\+|1|' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

If someone could explain how the expression works the first time and not the second and how to make it work, that'd be great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This worked for me in the end.

```
sed -i 's/^worker_processes.*/worker_processes 1;/' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```